# Llamada ajax por POST ejecuta funcion php dos veces

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Buenas a tod@s, tengo un problema con una llamada ajax a un método del controlador. El problema es que al ejecutarse el método, me graba en DB los mismos registros dos veces. Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera arrojarme algo de luz en el asunto.

Código Ajax:

---

```
<?php 
$script = <<< JS

    //estado inicial WorkFlow
    estado_origen = $('#orden-status').val();

    $('#w0').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        //estado seleccionado WorkFlow
        select = $('#orden-status').val();    

        // De EnCurso a PendienteRealizar:
        if (estado_origen == 'OrdenWorkflow/encurso' && select == 'OrdenWorkflow/pendienterealizar') {
             $('#modalEncursoPendiente').modal('show');
             $('#btn-modalEncursoPendiente-aceptar').click(function() {
                if($('#motivosvueltavisita').val() != ''){
                    var motivo = $("<input>")
                                 .attr("type", "hidden")
                                 .attr("name", "Orden[motivo]").val($('#motivosvueltavisita').val());
                    $('#w0').append($(motivo));
                    var obs = $("<input>")
                                 .attr("type", "hidden")
                                 .attr("name", "Orden[obs]").val($('#orden-obs').val());
                    $('#w0').append($(obs));
                }
                $('#modalEncursoPendiente').modal('hide');            
                $('#w0').unbind('submit').submit();
            });
        }
        // De EnCurso a Fin Conformidad: ***AQUI ESTA LA LLAMADA AJAX QUE ME DA PROBLEMA***
        else if (estado_origen == 'OrdenWorkflow/encurso' && select == 'OrdenWorkflow/finconfirmadas') {
            $('#modalConfirmadas').modal('show');
            $('#btn-modalConfirmadas-aceptar').click(function() {
                var keys = $('#exclusiones-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');           
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: '/orden/exclusiones/?id='+ $model->id_orden, 
                    type: 'post', 
                    data: {keylist: keys},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){  
                        $('#modalConfirmadas').modal('hide');            
                        //$('#w0').unbind('submit').submit();
                    }, 
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 

                    }       
                });             
            });
        }
        else{
            $('#w0').unbind('submit').submit();   
        }
    });

    $('#btn-modalEncursoPendiente-cerrar').click(function() {
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#pjax-orden'});
    });

    $('#btn-modalConfirmadas-cerrar').click(function() {
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#pjax-orden'});
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script); 
?>
```

---

y el código del controlador:

```
public function actionExclusiones($id)
    {    
        if (isset($_POST['keylist'])) {

            $keys = $_POST['keylist'];

            foreach ($keys as $value) {
                $exclusiones = new ROrdenExclusion();
                $exclusiones->id_exclusion = $value;
                $exclusiones->id_orden = $id;
                if (!$exclusiones->save()) {
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            return true;          
        }        
    }
```

---

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En general AJAX no está loco, hace lo que le pides, asegúrate que no haya  la misma invocación en la llamada de tu headers, helper o pedazo de código en HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que al hacer post se pierde la cancelación de la acción del evento "preventDefault()". Le añadí un segundo evento en el click del botón y con eso no hace la llamada ajax dos veces.

```
else if (estado_origen == 'OrdenWorkflow/encurso' && select == 'OrdenWorkflow/finconfirmadas') {
        $('#modalConfirmadas').modal('show');
        $('#btn-modalConfirmadas-aceptar').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //segunto evento de cancelación
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var keys = $('#exclusiones-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');           
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/orden/exclusiones/?id='+ $model->id_orden, 
                type: 'post', 
                data: {keylist: keys},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){  
                    $('#modalConfirmadas').modal('hide');            
                    $('#w0').unbind('submit').submit();
                }, 
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 

                }       
            });             
        });
}
```