# Primero hacer un onClick y después un submit del formulario o viceversa

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, codeigniter

tengo un problema con mi código.

Lo que pasa es que primero tenía mi formulario con el típico botón enviar, dentro coloque un onClick que llamaba una función JavaScript donde tenía un AJAX y ese AJAX llamaba a un controlador, lo que hacía es que ese formulario se enviaba al correo, pero ahora lo que hice fue que el formulario lo envié a un CRM y funciona correctamente pero también necesito que lo envíe al correo y es en ese punto donde no sé cómo hacerle ya que al dejar que lo envíe al CRM refresca la página y antes lo que solo lo enviaba al correo pero no refrescaba solo limpiaba el formulario nuevamente.

> Formulario que se envía al CRM

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="contact-box m-l-30">
                                            <!-- Note :
                                               - You can modify the font style and form style to suit your website.
                                               - Code lines with comments Do not remove this code   are required for the form to work properly, make sure that you do not remove these lines of code.
                                               - The Mandatory check script can modified as to suit your business needs.
                                               - It is important that you test the modified form before going live.-->
                                            <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' style='width:600px;margin:auto;'>

                                                <META HTTP-EQUIV ='content-type' CONTENT='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>

                                                <form id="form_contactanos" action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads54017000020400005 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatory54017000020400005()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
                                                        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='b8c6293891e2878f125a78c114c45d1133cd8ab0fd31519fb0e76a930012c594'/>
                                                        <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value=''/>
                                                        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='8a7419917526917cd8f7bdba23036d4e91d640f798fb7dcac4168b987edf63b4'/>
                                                        <input type='text' style='display:none;'  name='actionType' value='TGVhZHM='/>

                                                        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' value='https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;syntaxtecnologias.com.mx&#x2f;index.php&#x2f;Inicio_controller&#x2f;contactanos' />
                                                        <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
                                                        <style>
                                                        tr , td {
                                                        padding:6px;
                                                        border-spacing:0px;
                                                        border-width:0px;
                                                        }
                                                        </style>
                                                        <table style='width:600px;background-color:white;color:black'>

                                                            <h1 class="title font-light m-t-10">Contáctanos</h1>

                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <input id="txt_nombre" name="First Name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre(s)"> </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <input id="txt_apellido" name="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos"> </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <input id="txt_puesto" name="LEADCF31" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tu Puesto"> </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label>Giro de la Empresa</label>

                                                                        <select class="custom-select col-12" name='Industry'>
                                                                            <option value='-None-'>---Seleccione---</option>
                                                                            <option value='ASP'>ASP</option>
                                                                            <option value='Comercio&#x20;Electr&oacute;nico'>Comercio Electr&oacute;nico</option>
                                                                            <option value='Comercio&#x20;Exterior'>Comercio Exterior</option>
                                                                            <option value='Corporativo&#x2f;Grande'>Corporativo&#x2f;Grande</option>
                                                                            <option value='Educacion&#x2f;Capacitacion'>Educacion&#x2f;Capacitacion</option>
                                                                            <option value='Embajadas&#x20;y&#x20;Consulados'>Embajadas y Consulados</option>
                                                                            <option value='Empresas&#x20;de&#x20;Servicios'>Empresas de Servicios</option>
                                                                            <option value='Gobierno&#x2f;Militar'>Gobierno&#x2f;Militar</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Aeron&aacute;utica'>Industria Aeron&aacute;utica</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Automotriz'>Industria Automotriz</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;de&#x20;Alimentos'>Industria de Alimentos</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;de&#x20;la&#x20;Construcci&oacute;n'>Industria de la Construcci&oacute;n</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;de&#x20;las&#x20;Telecomunicaciones'>Industria de las Telecomunicaciones</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Energ&eacute;tica'>Industria Energ&eacute;tica</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Hotelera'>Industria Hotelera</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Inmobiliaria'>Industria Inmobiliaria</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Manufactura'>Industria Manufactura</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Maquiladora'>Industria Maquiladora</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Metalmecanica'>Industria Metalmecanica</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Minera'>Industria Minera</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Qu&iacute;mica'>Industria Qu&iacute;mica</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Textil'>Industria Textil</option>
                                                                            <option value='Industria&#x20;Tur&iacute;stica'>Industria Tur&iacute;stica</option>
                                                                            <option value='Inmobiliaria'>Inmobiliaria</option>
                                                                            <option value='ISP&#x20;&#x28;&#x20;Intenet&#x20;Service&#x20;Provider&#x29;'>ISP &#x28; Intenet Service Provider&#x29;</option>
                                                                            <option value='Proyectos&#x20;de&#x20;Infraestructura'>Proyectos de Infraestructura</option>
                                                                            <option value='PyME&#x2f;Mediana&#x20;Empresa'>PyME&#x2f;Mediana Empresa</option>
                                                                            <option value='Salud'>Salud</option>
                                                                            <option value='Sector&#x20;Financiero&#x20;y&#x20;Bancos'>Sector Financiero y Bancos</option>
                                                                            <option value='Servicios&#x20;Financieros,&#x20;inmobiliarios&#x20;y&#x20;de&#x20;Alquiler'>Servicios Financieros, inmobiliarios y de Alquiler</option>
                                                                            <option value='Servicios&#x20;Tecnicos&#x20;Profesionales,&#x20;Personales&#x20;y&#x20;Soc'>Servicios Tecnicos Profesionales, Personales y Soc</option>
                                                                            <option value='SoHo&#x2f;Micro&#x20;Empresa'>SoHo&#x2f;Micro Empresa</option>
                                                                            <option value='Transportes&#x20;y&#x20;Comunicaciones'>Transportes y Comunicaciones</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <input id="txt_ubicacion" name="Street" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ubicación"> </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <input id="txt_telefono" name="Phone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Teléfono"> </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group m-t-10">
                                                                    <textarea id="txt_mensaje" name="LEADCF30" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LctHHEUAAAAAP99bIMWKIoyMLzEaFnsz0XF2Tpx"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info-gradiant btn-md m-t-20 btn-arrow"><span> ENVIAR <i class="ti-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <script>
                                                            var mndFileds=new Array('First Name','Last Name','Phone');
                                                            var fldLangVal=new Array('Nombre','Apellido','Phone');
                                                            var name='';
                                                            var email='';

                                                            function checkMandatory54017000020400005() {
                                                                enviar_password();
                                                                for(i=0;i<mndFileds.length;i++) {
                                                                    var fieldObj=document.forms['WebToLeads54017000020400005'][mndFileds[i]];
                                                                    if(fieldObj) {
                                                                        if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length==0) {
                                                                            if(fieldObj.type =='file') {
                                                                                alert('Please select a file to upload.');
                                                                                fieldObj.focus();
                                                                                return false;
                                                                            }
                                                                            alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be empty.');
                                                                            fieldObj.focus();
                                                                            return false;
                                                                        } else if (fieldObj.nodeName=='SELECT') {
                                                                            if(fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value=='-None-') {
                                                                                alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be none.');
                                                                                fieldObj.focus();
                                                                                return false;
                                                                            }
                                                                        } else if(fieldObj.type =='checkbox'){
                                                                            if(fieldObj.checked == false){
                                                                                alert('Please accept  '+fldLangVal[i]);
                                                                                fieldObj.focus();
                                                                                return false;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                        try {
                                                                            if(fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
                                                                                name = fieldObj.value;
                                                                            }
                                                                        } catch (e) {}
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                        </script>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

El código así solo funciona, pero necesito que también se lleve a cabo la función de JavaScript enviar_password(). Antes lo tenía con un onClick y ejecutaba el JavaScript, pero desde que también lo tengo que enviar al CRM ya se me complico.

> Función JavaScript que también necesito que se ejecute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function enviar_password() {
          var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha' ),
              response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

          if (response.length === 0) {
            swal("Algo salió mal!", "Valida el reCAPTCHA por favor!", "error");
          } else {
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Inicio_controller/enviar_mensaje');?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#form_contactanos').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                    document.getElementById("form_contactanos").reset(); 
                    swal("Buen trabajo!", "Tu mensaje ha sido enviado!", "success");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    swal("Algo salió mal!", "Error al enviar tu mensaje!", "error");
                }
            });
          }
        }
    </script>
```

El recapcha no lo está tomando en cuenta por el momento ya que en el JavaScript valido que ese seleccionado.

> Controlador que envia el correo.

```
public function enviar_mensaje() {

  $nombre = $this->input->post('txt_nombre');
  $puesto = $this->input->post('txt_puesto');
  $giro = $this->input->post('txt_giro');
  $ubicacion = $this->input->post('txt_ubicacion');
  $telefono = $this->input->post('txt_telefono');
  $mensaje = $this->input->post('txt_mensaje');

  $from_email = "xxx@gmail.com";
  $from_password = 'xxx';

  $to_email = 'rrr@gmail.com';

  //Load email library
  //$this->load->library('email');

  $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => $from_email,
    'smtp_pass' => $from_password,
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
  );

  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

  $this->email->from($from_email, 'abacom Telecomunicaciones');
  $this->email->to($to_email);
  $this->email->subject('Cotizacion Web');
  $this->email->message('hola');
  //Send mail
  if($this->email->send()){
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
  } 
      //$this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","You have encountered an error");
  //$this->load->view('contact_email_form');
}
```

Coloque el onClick en el botón pero el problema en general es que primero envía al CRM y refresca y no hace el onClick

Comment: la implementación (función) del onclick lleva un parámetro que es el evento, para evitar que el formulario se envíe hay que capturarlo al inicio con un `event.preventDefault();`  y cancelar al final con un `return false;`

Comment: Si entendi pero no se en que parte del JavaScript lo debo de poner

Comment: aquí hay algo parecido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93619/81450

Comment: En el form, puedes cambiar esto: `return checkMandatory54017000020400005()` por esto: `return checkMandatory54017000020400005(event)`  y en el código JS, modificas esa función así:  `function checkMandatory54017000020400005(e) { /*esto antes que todo*/ e.preventDefault(); /*resto del codigo*/ return false;}`

Comment: Y pongo el onclick en el boton?